# What is the easiest way to find non-vulnerable container images?

Tags: docker, container, kubernetes

I am fairly new to container image vulnerability scanning. There seem to be a lot of tools (Snyk, Trivvy, Clair, e.g.) that can identify vulnerable packages in container images. They also do a good job identifying the fix version for the individual package (example: for CVE-2022-32207, upgrade from curl 7.80.0-r1 to 7.80.0-r1).

However, this is not exactly what I'm looking for. Since we're using a base image of Debian or Alpine, what I really want to know is...which version of Debian/Alpine includes the fix version, if any.

Is there an easy way to search base images (Debian/Alpine) to determine which vulnerabilities are present in each version? That way I can instruct my developers, upgrade your base to the latest version and you'll be done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way (if you're a company anyway) is to have an internal registry you manage yourselves and maintain upgrades there.

Docker Hub official images are a reasonable place to start but they may not get upgraded enough for your use case.

Also if you're using debian derived images watch out for the [ignore unfixed](https://raesene.github.io/blog/2020/11/22/When_Is_A_Vulnerability_Not_A_Vulnerability/) problem.

Another approach to this problem to reduce vulns, if it suits your development style is to use ["distroless" images](https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/distroless) which are much more stripped down and require less patching.